# SQL/T-SQL. Create ranges from numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have a table numbers ex :

```
  nums
  _____
| 54902 |
| 54903 | 
| 54901 | 
| 54904 | 
| 54905 | 
| 3487  | 
| 3457  | 
| 789   | 
| 790   | 
| 54906 | 
| 791   | 
| 76253 |
```

I'd like create ranges from this set like (if is this possible...):

```
54901-54906
3487
3457 
789-791
76253
```

Any tips?

Comment: Are you going to use the ranges in other sql code or some sql report? otherwise it might be easier to do this in the client code if possible.

Answer (score 7):

For obtaining this kind of ranges. First, you should group sequential numbers - to achieve this, you can use `gaps-and-islands` approach -. After that, you can get `max` and `min` numbers for each group easily.

```
DECLARE @nums TABLE(num int)
INSERT INTO @nums VALUES
( 54902 ),
( 54903 ), 
( 54901 ), 
( 54904 ), 
( 54905 ), 
( 3487  ), 
( 3457  ), 
( 789   ), 
( 790   ), 
( 54906 ), 
( 791   ), 
( 76253 )


SELECT CAST(MIN(num) AS varchar(10)) 
    + CASE WHEN MAX(num) > MIN(num) THEN '-' + CAST(MAX(num) AS varchar(10)) ELSE '' END  
FROM ( 
    SELECT num, num - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num) AS GRP 
    FROM @nums 
) AS T
GROUP BY GRP
```

Result:

```
---------------------
789-791
3457
3487
54901-54906
76253
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if you could add a textual explanation of what the code does. I've changed the code formatting a little to make it more readable, but the explanation should be added by you.